# Creating a two-column-100% layout with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, layout, web

So I'm trying to create a layout with twitter bootstrap and Ryan Fait's sticky footer

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header"></div>

    <div class="user-panel">
      <h1>Side Panel</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="content">Hello World!</div>

    <div class="push"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</body>
```

I can't seem to expand the user-panel and content to 100% height, tried these, but they don't work:

http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?868712-100-height-sidebar-background

http://fiddle.jshell.net/teresko/UG8Rk/show/ **I need the rounded borders so...**

Here's the CSS:

```css
/* Header */
.header {
    height: 40px;
    margin-top: 0px;

    border: 1px solid #999;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: #666 0px 1px 1px;
    -moz-box-shadow: #666 0px 1px 1px;
    box-shadow: #666 0px 1px 1px;
    background: #f3f3f1;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 bottom, from(#f3f3f1), to(#2b2b2b));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#f3f3f1, #2b2b2b);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#f3f3f1, #2b2b2b);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#f3f3f1, #2b2b2b);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#f3f3f1, #2b2b2b);
    background: linear-gradient(#f3f3f1, #2b2b2b);
    -pie-background: linear-gradient(#f3f3f1, #2b2b2b);
    behavior: url(/PIE.htc);
}
/* End of Header */

/* Footer */
.footer {
    margin-top: 12px;
    background-color: #000;

    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    clear: both;
    height: 40px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: #666 0px 1px 1px;
    -moz-box-shadow: #666 0px 1px 1px;
    box-shadow: #666 0px 1px 1px;
    background: #f3f3f1;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 bottom, from(#f3f3f1), to(#2b2b2b));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#f3f3f1, #2b2b2b);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#f3f3f1, #2b2b2b);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#f3f3f1, #2b2b2b);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#f3f3f1, #2b2b2b);
    background: linear-gradient(#f3f3f1, #2b2b2b);
    -pie-background: linear-gradient(#f3f3f1, #2b2b2b);
    behavior: url(/PIE.htc);
}
/* End of Footer */

/* Sticky footer by Ryan Fait... with a little customization*/
* {
    margin: 0;
}

html,
body {
    height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -4em;
}

.push {
    height: 40px;
    clear: both;
}
/* End of Sticky footer*/

/* User Panel ( that sidepanel on the left side with navigation etc) */
.user-panel {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: #666 0px 1px 1px;
    -moz-box-shadow: #666 0px 1px 1px;
    box-shadow: #666 0px 1px 1px;
    background: #f3f3f1;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 bottom, from(#f3f3f1), to(#2b2b2b));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#f3f3f1, #2b2b2b);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#f3f3f1, #2b2b2b);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(#f3f3f1, #2b2b2b);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#f3f3f1, #2b2b2b);
    background: linear-gradient(#f3f3f1, #2b2b2b);
    -pie-background: linear-gradient(#f3f3f1, #2b2b2b);
    behavior: url(/PIE.htc);
    width: 175px;
    float: left;
    height: inherit;
    background: gray;
}
/* End of User Panel */
```

Any help is appreciated... thanks...

EDIT:

Thanks to Andrea Ligios for the fiddle!

http://jsfiddle.net/RPFcN/2/

Works well with Firefox, but doesn't work on Chrome...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can place this code inside your side-panel element:

```
.user-panel {
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    height:auto;
    bottom:0;
    top:0;
    ...
    // Rest of the properties
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hi hello good morning my beloved officemate from across my cube. Thank you... I adjusted some values to account for the header and footer height. It works, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use calc() CSS3 function.

Look at here: http://jsfiddle.net/RPFcN/2/

You specify `display: inline-block` to keep the blocks displayed in line, but with block element behaviour;

Then you set the `height` of the `user-panel` to be 100% minus the height of header and footer, their margins and borders (total: 98px).

The height of the "content" will be 100% minus 94px, because content has no borders (while user-panel has 1px of borders).

EDIT: and you remove `height: auto !important` from wrapper class

Comment: works well with Firefox, sidepanel and content aren't still 100% height in Chrome... also, is there any other way to do this without using CSS3?

Answer (score 1):

The way I have used to make this work is...

> HTML:

```
<footer>
  <div class="container">
    <p class="text-muted">Footer text you want here.</p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

> CSS:

```
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  margin-bottom: 8em; /* Must be set to the same as footer height */
}
footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 8em; /* Must be set at the same as margin-bottom in body */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add `display:inline-block` to the `.user-panel` and `.wrapper`